# How nginx multiplexes a single socket

Tags: sockets, events, nginx, request

I've been reading about nginx internals where they mentioned nginx master process creates several worker processes and each of these processes wait for connections on the same port. This is possible with fork since the fd struct is shared between the processes. What I don't understand is, if this is how it works, then wont there be a race condition within `accept(fd)` across multiple processes? Maybe my understanding of how worker processes accept request is not clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is allowed to have multiple listeners (threads or processess) `accept`ing on the same socket. Upon initiated connection one (and only one of them) is guaranteed to return from `accept` call.

On the side note, you are also allowed to have multiple listeners `recvfrom`ing the same socket (TCP-flavor `recv`ing as well, but this is of uncertain value).

Comment: That clears most of the things! So each worker process is like an event loop waiting on the fd's it accepted?

Comment: How exactly would multiple listeners to recvfrom be beneficial?

Comment: @FaizHalde, if every datagram can be processed independently (which is often the case) that will give you very easy way to paralellize processing of them.